# Is there any way to modify images from a theme using the web interface?

Tags: themes, images, admin, uploads, customization

Is there any way to modify images from a theme using the Wordpress web interface?

Comment: Do you mean to edit default theme images like arrows, icons, header images, or list style images?

Comment: Yes, I did add my own child theme and I want to add some images to it.

Comment: You need an uploader plugin like the one suggested by thunderror.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [WP easy uploader plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-easy-uploader/) to add images/files via WP interface

Comment: Sorry but this plugin is almost useless, it doesn't let you choose the exact location where to upload the file. I found another plugin that is supposed to do this but it doesn't work with 3.x, is named [wp-filemanager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-filemanager/)

Comment: I think you need to look again. It lets you specify the path(exact location) where you want the file to go to. (If the directory doesn't exist, its even created.)